# I am having issues concatenating two JSON values to perform a !contains in my Karate Scenario, if I run the match for each field individually it works

Tags: karate

```
def concatField = 
{'#(responseartikel[].Kurztext_1 + responseartikel[*].Kurztext_2)'}

match concatField !contains expected
```

*But I get an **error**: `"net.minidev.json.parser.parseexception unexpected character ( })"` at **position 66**."

---

Is there another way to define this concatenated field without writing a java utility?*

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately there is no other way.